# Как создать ассоциативный массив из SQL-запроса в red beans?

Tags: php, sql, redbeanphp

У меня есть одна таблица, которая хранит id отдела и id участка, относящегося к этому отделу. В каждом отделе(division) может быть несколько участков(district):

```
division_id|district_id
-----------------------
13         |          7
13         |          8
13         |          9
21         |          15
21         |          16
21         |          17
```

Если выполнить запрос "SELECT * FROM division_district_table", то **red beans** вернет массив типа:

```
[
  [0]=>['division_id' => 13, 'district_id'=> 7],
  [1]=>['division_id' => 13, 'district_id'=> 8],
  [2]=>['division_id' => 13, 'district_id'=> 9],

  [3]=>['division_id' => 21, 'district_id'=> 15],
  [4]=>['division_id' => 21, 'district_id'=> 16],
  [5]=>['division_id' => 21, 'district_id'=> 17],
]
```

Вопрос: как мне создать ассоциативный массив с помощью **red beans**, где ключом будет **division_id**, а его значением - массив с **district_id**? Например:

```
[
  [13]=>[7, 8, 9],
  [21]=>[15, 16, 17]
]
```

Если есть инструменты, которые как раз направлены на такой род задач или самописные решения, то буду рад рассмотреть любой вариант.

Comment: Есть. Такой инструмент называется "цикл". В цикле можно перебрать исходный массив и добавить значения в новый. В РНР оператором перебора массива в цикле является foreach. А redbean использовать не надо. Ни для этой задачи, ни для какой-либо другой. Потом придется очень пожалеть, что купились на дешевые заманухи шарлатана из ютубы.

Comment: Когда дело касается вложенности одного уровня, то цикл легко решает эту проблему, но когда вложенностей больше, например, трех, то возникает большая проблема. Просто, redbean уже используется в этой системе и я решил как то его подключить.

Comment: Еще интересен момент: если Left join`ов много, то информация часто дублируется, а сильно ли это влияет на скорость или память? Что делать в таком случае, тоже бы было интересно узнать

Comment: вложенность здесь вообще никакой роли не играет, пусть хоть 10 будет, алгоритм будет ровно тот же. из всего программирования здесь надо знать только перебор массива в цикле и присвоение значения элементу массива